# Get SATA Drive Location

Tags: c++, windows, driver, device, ioctl

I have a computer with SATA drives and code, which through Windows 7, returned location information as SCSI_ADDRESS. The following code works fine for Windows 7.

```
typedef struct _SCSI_ADDRESS {
    ULONG Length;
    UCHAR PortNumber;
    UCHAR PathId;
    UCHAR TargetId;
    UCHAR Lun;
}SCSI_ADDRESS, *PSCSI_ADDRESS;

char[256] FileName;
strcpy(FileName, "\\?\ide#diskcrucial_ct250mx200ssd1__________________mu02____#4&1f5e0e69&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}");

m_deviceHandle = CreateFile(FileName,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            0,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING,
            0);

SCSI_ADDRESS m_sa;
memset ((void *)&m_sa, 0, sizeof(SCSI_ADDRESS));
m_sa.Length = sizeof(SCSI_ADDRESS);
if (!DeviceIoControl(IOCTL_SCSI_GET_ADDRESS, &m_sa, sizeof(SCSI_ADDRESS), &m_sa, sizeof(SCSI_ADDRESS), &cbBytesReturned))
{
}
```

Under Windows 10, the Intel SATA driver returns a success code (true), but leaves the SCSI information as zeroes. I do notice that through Device Manager or Disk Management that the location is different for each SATA disk.

[image: Location information showing in Device Manager for the SATA drive]

**How do I obtain the location information?**

I have an open link to the device and can obtain IOCTL_SCSI_* everything, just not the location ID.

**Hardware**

The disk attaches to the internal Intel SATA controller.

Controller: `Intel ICH8R/DH/DO SATA AHCI Controller`

Driver: `iaStor.sys`

Version: `8.9.0.1023`

I am open to possibly a different driver that renders SCSI information, though the question would still be valid, as the Intel driver works.

**UPDATE:**

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/51zpj9/location_information_for_a_disk_drive/) post, which indicates to use 'get-disk | select *' in PowerShell. I do see location information

```
Location              : Integrated : Adapter 0 : Channel 0 : Device 0
```

The information is not exactly "3" or "2", as shown in Device Manager. This method would be a pain in C++. I really am hoping for a Setupdi API or IOCTL method that obtains location information.

These two links, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8541374/get-physical-disk-paths) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263380/send-ioctl-to-windows-device-driver-createfile-fails), are interesting but not very helpful, so I list them here as part of my research. I already have the device path, hence unnecessary.

[This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ba183a5-71bb-4601-beb6-73ba20b087cd/getting-the-propertydata-of-managementobject-in-c?forum=vcgeneral) link talks about implementing `ManagementObjectSearcher` in C++.